# Getting Pypy to recognize third party modules

Tags: python, pypy, pytables

Just a quick question, how do I get pypy to recognize third pary modules that I have in Python? For instance, I get the following error.

```
from tables import *
ImportError: No Module named tables
```

Which is basically saying that it cannot find my pytables library that I use to interact with in the script I am trying to run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For pure python modules, just add the directory containing the modules to your sys.path, using something like:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/lib')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser('~/lib'))
```

This works for CPython, Pypy and Jython.

For C extension modules, you can try Pypy's cpyext, but it won't run everything you might hope for, because some CPython C extension modules wander into dark corners of CPython's C-based runtime:
http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-cpython-extension-modules-with.html

I sometimes write code that uses ctypes to interface with a C .so, and then use that on both CPython and Pypy, because they both do pretty well with ctypes - but ctypes can be kinda slow on CPython:
http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html
Last I checked, Jython had the beginnings of ctypes, but it wasn't far enough along to use, at least not for my purposes.

There's also a new interface that requires a C compiler at runtime.  It'll likely be less brittle (read: prone to segfaults) than ctypes.  It's described here:
http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2012/06/release-01-of-cffi.html
It comes from the Pypy project I believe, but it was made to work first on CPython.  AFAIK, it doesn't yet run on Pypy.

Answer (score 6):

Pypy has a separate install space.  Therefore, any modules you want to install from pypi should be installed into its space.  So, for instance, I have pypy installed in /usr/local/pypy-1.9-32bit

I recommend using pip or easy_install.  Here's how to install pip:

```
curl curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | /usr/local/pypy-1.9-32bit/bin/pypy
```

or

```
curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | /usr/local/pypy-1.9-32bit/bin/pypy
```

Then, just use the newly installed pip to get the module:

```
sudo /usr/local/pypy-1.9-32bit/bin/pip install tables
```

In this case, it failed, with the following error:

```
bminton@bminton:/tmp$ sudo /usr/local/pypy-1.9-32bit/bin/pip install tables
Downloading/unpacking tables
  Downloading tables-2.4.0.tar.gz (8.9Mb): 8.9Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package tables
    .. ERROR:: You need numpy 1.4.1 or greater to run PyTables!
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    .. ERROR:: You need numpy 1.4.1 or greater to run PyTables!
```

Installation failed in this case, because Tables depends on Numpy, which is not yet supported by PyPy (although they are working on it, see http://pypy.org/numpydonate.html).  However, for many python modules, this method works great.  For instance, I successfully installed the logilab constraint package this way.

Comment: http://python-distribute.org has been taken over by a link farm, and setuptools should probably be used instead anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in other answers, `pypy` has a separate space for installed modules. I find the easiest way to add a module to pypy is the following:

- download the source (e.g. as a `*.tar.gz` file)
- extract, `cd` into the extracted directory
- run `pypy setup.py install` (sometimes you need to prepend a `sudo`)

Comment: i did that, it installed the lib successfully but i am getting errors again for a module i imported in python code

Answer (score 3):

Copy folder for the module from C:\Python27\Lib to C:\pypy-2.3.1-win32\lib-python or the equivalent of where you have them installed.

Obviously, this will only work on Windows.

Comment: I very nearly flagged this because you started with "I have this problem too..." Just give the answer. Nothing more, nothing less. Not a bad first post though!

Comment: (You edited it, gave your advice and even some encouragement -- to a quite helpful answer, indeed. But what exact purpose you think the added "threat" served? This flag-waving is utterly unnecessary and intimidating to a newbie. And you probably know that. I do, for sure, being a newbie myself.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is pip_pypy when you install pypy. See here:

[image: screenshot].

Then install third module with pip_pypy.